# HOW TO USE CASE---WHEN-----END IN SQL VIEW

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to test a field in a table based on certain number when does number are found then the corresponding values should replace those fields, i want the checking to happen within a view
 below is what i have done so far.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @SQL='CREATE VIEW VW_DEMOGRAPHIC AS
BEGIN
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP(120) REPLACE(a.Lastname,a.Lastname,''Hidden'')as   Lastname 
,REPLACE(a.Firstname,a.Firstname,''Hidden'')as Firstname 
CASE b.MaritalStatus
WHEN ''42'' THEN ''SINGLE''
WHEN ''43'' THEN ''MARRIED''
WHEN ''44'' THEN ''WIDOW''
WHEN ''47'' THEN ''DIVORCE''
WHEN ''189'' THEN ''SEPERATED''
END as [Marital Status]
from VW_PatientDetail a
join mst_Patient b on a.Ptn_pk = b.Ptn_Pk GROUP BY a.AGE,a.Lastname,    a.Firstname, b.MaritalStatus'
exec (@sql1)
END
```

if i run the select part it work fine but within sql view the column [Marital Status] is resulting to Null.
 i will appreciate any help to fix this problem

Comment: 1) what are valid values for MartialStatus? (int, varchar, etc.).  2) you may need an else clause to handle a default value that does not exist in your 'when' clauses:

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ELSE` otherwise the `CASE` will return `NULL` if none of the conditions are matched.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181765.aspx

> ELSE else_result_expression
>
> Is the expression returned if no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE. If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL